# Extjs window inside panel

Tags: extjs

I need to put a window control inside a panel control and constrain the window inside this panel.

this is my code resumed:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MainWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
alias: 'widget.mainwindow',

layout: 'vbox',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 50,
        width: '100%',
        layout: 'hbox'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 400,
        width: '100%',
        layout: 'hbox',

        items:[
            window1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {autoShow:true, width:90}),
            window2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {autoShow:true, width:400})
        ]
    }
],
```

With this code, the both windows appears on top of each other.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve? Windows are by definition floating.  Also, not sure your assignments inside an array are going to compile.

Comment: I need to make a vertical menu (http://postimage.org/image/c4io120u5/) that appears on top of other controls.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this problems using border layout, and changing the VerticalMenu base class to Panel.
In fact, only the horizontal menus need to be on top of other controls:

http://postimage.org/image/3mdmo55n9/

Thanks